MySQL, why doesn't the subquery use a range scan?
MySQL version: 5.7.44
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`.`b`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`.`a`;

CREATE TABLE `test`.`a` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `type` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `type_created_at_idx` (`type` , `created_at`)
)  ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8MB4;

INSERT INTO `test`.`a` (`id`, `type`, `created_at`) VALUES
(1, 'A', '2024-08-31'),
(2, 'A', '2024-08-30'),
(3, 'B', '2024-08-29'),
(4, 'B', '2024-08-28'),
(5, 'C', '2024-08-27'),
(6, 'C', '2024-08-26'),
(7, 'C', '2024-08-25'),
(8, 'D', '2024-08-24'),
(9, 'D', '2024-08-23'),
(10, 'E', '2024-08-22');

CREATE TABLE `test`.`b` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `name_type_idx` (`name`,`type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `test`.`b` (`type`, `name`) VALUES
('A', 'admin'),
('B', 'admin'),
('C', 'user'),
('D', 'user'),
('E', 'user');


EXPLAIN 1

EXPLAIN SELECT
  `a`.`id`
FROM
    `test`.`a`
WHERE
    `a`.`type` IN 
    ('A', 'B')
    AND `a`.`created_at` >= '2024-08-30';




id
select_type
table
partitions
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
filtered
Extra




1
SIMPLE
a

range
type_created_at_idx
type_created_at_idx
187

3
100.00
Using where; Using index




EXPLAIN 2

EXPLAIN SELECT
  `a`.`id`
FROM
    `test`.`a`
WHERE
    `a`.`type` IN 
    (SELECT `b`.`type` FROM `test`.`b` WHERE `b`.`name` = 'admin')
    AND `a`.`created_at` >= '2024-08-30';




id
select_type
table
partitions
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
filtered
Extra




1
SIMPLE
b

ref
name_type_idx
name_type_idx
182
const
2
100.00
Using index; LooseScan


1
SIMPLE
a

ref
type_created_at_idx
type_created_at_idx
182
test.b.type
1
33.33
Using where; Using index



EXPLAIN 1 works as expected, using range scan and filtered is 100.
As shown in EXPLAIN 2. When I replace the contents of IN with the equivalent query, MySQL no longer uses a range scan, and filtered is 33.33.
What causes this? How do I make EXPLAIN 2's filtered to be 100?

Literals list and subquery output is not the same. Even if the values sets are the same (which is random).

Does this mean EXPLAIN 1 is better than EXPLAIN 2?

They differs - this is the only thing which we can say.

You essentially have two range tests in the WHERE clause -- IN and >=.  The optimizer will help with one or the other of them, but not both.
UNION is a workaround for some situations:
SELECT  `a`.`id`
    FROM  `test`.`a`
    WHERE  `a`.`type` = 'A'
      AND  `a`.`created_at` >= '2024-08-30
UNION ALL
SELECT  `a`.`id`
    FROM  `test`.`a`
    WHERE  `a`.`type` = 'B'
      AND  `a`.`created_at` >= '2024-08-30';

Then it will use both parts of this for both SELECTs:
INDEX(`type` , `created_at`)   -- in this order (as you have it)

Note:  UNION ALL is faster than UNION (aka UNION_DISTINCT).  It should be appropriate for this query, but not for some other similar queries.

This looks good, but is it still suitable when the number of types reaches tens of thousands?

10K SELECTs connected by UNION would probably be less efficient than IN with 10K constants.
